# MySQL Order By Case Casting Tinyint to String

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    display_order
FROM 
    data_element_value
WHERE 
       key_id = 32
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN (display_order IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        display_order
    ELSE 
        `value` 
    END
```

The expected output is :

```
id                    display_order
1                     1
13                    2
15                    3
16                    10
```

But, I'm getting:

```
id                    display_order
1                     1
16                    10
13                    2
15                    3
```

I've tried casting the `display_order` to `UNSIGNED` as such:

```
CASE WHEN (display_order IS NOT NULL) THEN
    CAST(display_order as UNSIGNED)
ELSE
    `VALUE`
END
```

I've also tried:

```
CASE WHEN (display_order IS NOT NULL) THEN
    display_order + 0
ELSE
    `VALUE`
END
```

But this does not seem to help.

The column data type is `tinyint(2), unsigned, and allow nulls` for `display_order`

**EDIT**

Here is `describe data_element_value`

```
Field           Type                Null    Key Default Extra
id              int(11)             NO      PRI (null)  auto_increment
key_id          int(11)             NO      MUL (null)  
value           varchar(50)         NO          (null)  
sub_title       varchar(125)        YES         (null)  
chart_color     char(7)             YES         (null)  
display_order   tinyint(2) unsigned YES         (null)
```

Is there something I can do to correct this?

Comment: what is the output of `describe data_element_value`?

Comment: can you post your table example? it ill be interesting testing a solution using the same rows

Comment: @cegfault I added the describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `order by` without a `case` or `coalesce` statement and it will work just fine.

```
SELECT
    id,
    display_order
FROM 
    data_element_value
WHERE 
       key_id = 32
ORDER BY `display_order`, `value`
```

Comment: You are making assumptions about the OP's intended business logic which has not been given in the question.  However, given [the recent comment to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859612/mysql-order-by-case-casting-tinyint-to-string/28859757?noredirect=1#comment45985846_28859757), this may indeed be what was actually being sought.

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

> The return type of a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression is the compatible aggregated type of all return values, but also depends on the context in which it is used. If used in a string context, the result is returned as a string. If used in a numeric context, the result is returned as a decimal, real, or integer value.

Since your `value` column is a string type, you will have to `CAST` either the `value` column alone, or else the entire `CASE` expression, to achieve your desired result.  [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) would also be more concise than `CASE` in this instance:

```
SELECT
    id,
    display_order
FROM 
    data_element_value
WHERE 
    key_id = 32
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(display_order, CAST(`value` AS UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: *update* - This worked like a charm (kind of). It's not sorting on the `value` column, only the display_order column.

Comment: @GreenChili: For those records where `display_order IS NULL`, `value` should be used instead... is that not what you were after?  Did you mean to sort first by `display_order` and then, within records that have a matching `display_order`, sort by `value`?  If so, you simply want `ORDER BY display_order, \`value\``.

Comment: Not necessarily sorting first by display_order, and then by value. I'm looking to sort by display_order if it is not null, and by value (which could be any string value) if display_order is null. From looking at the response from WonderCricket, and now your comment. It appears that just a simple 'order by display_order, value' will work just fine.

Comment: @GreenChili: Suppose you have the following `(display_id, value)` records—`(1,1), (1,3), (2,1), (NULL,2)`; in what order should they be returned?

Comment: If I had the following (id, display_order, value) records - (1, 1, 'b'), (2, 2, 'a'), (3, null, 'b'), (4, null, 'a'). It would return (by id): 1, 2, 4, 3